# Parametrization of a spherical triangle?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I want to calculate an integral in the curve defined by a spherical triangle with vertices $\left(a,0,0\right),\left(0,a,0\right),\left(0,0,a\right)$ over the sphere of center $\left(0,0,0\right)$, and I would like to have a parametrization in 1 variable in order to do it, and I don't know how since the sphere itself has a parametrization in 2 variables. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your spherical triangle a curve or a surface?

Comment: @Henry It's a curve.

Comment: A closed curve with three edges? Split them up. You can have one side as $(a\cos \theta, a \sin \theta,0)$ then the next as  $(0,a\cos \phi, a \sin \phi)$ and the third as  $(a \sin \psi,0,a\cos \psi)$

Comment: @Henry Every angle goes from 0 to $\pi/2$ I guess?

Comment: That should work